# Narrow union types for custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, narrowing

I have 4 objects with few similar keys & a few different keys. I am using their union for database operations like so ->

`type Objects = Food | Diary | Plan | Recipe ;`

### Pagination custom hook

```
function usePaginate (key: string, options: Options) {
    const [data,setData] = useState<Objects[]>([]);
    const perPage = 10;
    const [first, setFirst] = useState(0);
    const [last, setLast] = useState(perPage);

    const links = () => data.slice(first,last);

    function paginate(clicked: 'next' | 'previous') {
        if(clicked === 'next' && data.length > (first+perPage)) {
            setFirst(first+perPage);
            setLast(last+perPage);
        }
        if(clicked === 'previous' && (first-perPage) >= 0) {
            setFirst(first-perPage);
            setLast(last-perPage);
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        setData(getData(key,options));
    },[])

    return [links(),paginate] as const;
}
```

### Calling custom hook in StockDisplay component

```
const StockDisplay = () => {
    const [foods, paginate] = usePaginate('foods',{'sort':['-stocked','info.name']});
    return (<>{foods.map(food => <Stock data={food} key={food.id} />)}</>)
    // I have also tried adding a check like below but the error persists. 'stocked' is a key that only exists in Food type
    return (<>{('stocked' in foods) && foods.map(food => <Stock data={food} key={food.id} />)}</>)
}
```

At this point, foods' type is `const foods: Objects[]` & paginate's type is `const paginate: (clicked: "next" | "previous") => void`. But the return line throws this error ->

```
Type 'Objects' is not assignable to type 'Food'.ts(2322)
Stock.tsx(12, 26): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { data: Food; }'
```

This is because in the Stock component below, data is defined to be the type `Food` but in the above StockDisplay component, I'm receiving `Objects[]`.

### Stock component

```
const Stock = ({data} : {data: Food}) => {
     return (
          <></>
     )
}
```

My question is, **How do I narrow down `Objects[]` output from the hook to just `Food[]` in StockDisplay component ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Quick workaround using type casting**

```
const StockDisplay = () => {
    const [foods, paginate] = usePaginate('foods',{'sort':['-stocked','info.name']});
    return (<>{(foods as Food[]).map(food => <Stock data={food} key={food.id} />)}</>)
    // I have also tried adding a check like below but the error persists. 'stocked' is a key that only exists in Food type
    return (<>{('stocked' in foods) && foods.map(food => <Stock data={food} key={food.id} />)}</>)
}
```

**2. Using generics**

```
function usePaginate<T>(key: string, options: Options): readonly [T[], (clicked: 'next' | 'previous') => void] {
    const [data,setData] = useState<Objects[]>([]);
    const perPage = 10;
    const [first, setFirst] = useState(0);
    const [last, setLast] = useState(perPage);

    const links = () => data.slice(first,last);

    function paginate(clicked: 'next' | 'previous') {
        if(clicked === 'next' && data.length > (first+perPage)) {
            setFirst(first+perPage);
            setLast(last+perPage);
        }
        if(clicked === 'previous' && (first-perPage) >= 0) {
            setFirst(first-perPage);
            setLast(last-perPage);
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        setData(getData(key,options));
    },[])

    return [links(),paginate] as const;
}
```

```
const StockDisplay = () => {
    const [foods, paginate] = usePaginate<Food>('foods',{'sort':['-stocked','info.name']});
    return (<>{foods.map(food => <Stock data={food} key={food.id} />)}</>)
    // I have also tried adding a check like below but the error persists. 'stocked' is a key that only exists in Food type
    return (<>{('stocked' in foods) && foods.map(food => <Stock data={food} key={food.id} />)}</>)
}
```

Comment: Type casting worked perfectly. What do you think about [using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) ?

Comment: @NarayanWaraich You could use type predicates, but I think it will require more code. I would use type predicates if the returning type is unknown until runtime. (ex. your key argument to `usePaginate` is unpredictable)